# How to make an application run at Fedora startup?

Tags: fedora, rtorrent, fedora-15

I've got a fresh install of Fedora 15 that I've set up. I want it to be able to download podcasts++ so I've installed `rtorrent`.

But how do I make `rtorrent` start up along with the OS?

Also, does anyone know where the conf file for `rtorrent` is? I don't want it to melt my router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gnome 3 it doesn't seem to be that easy yet. Here's [a workaround though](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/test/2011-March/098331.html). Note that this should work for any application, but I can't try it with `rtorrent`. Just report back if you have problems.

---

Let's find out the path of `rtorrent` first. Open up a terminal and enter:

```
which rtorrent
```

Remember this path. Then, try the following:

```
 mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
 cd !$
 gedit rtorrent.desktop &
```

Gedit should open and let you edit this file. In this file, enter the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/rtorrent
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=rtorrent
Name=rtorrent
```

Where it says `/path/to/rtorrent`, enter the path you've found out before. Then, save the file and close Gedit and the terminal. Now you need to restart Gnome and the application should start with your desktop session.

Comment: I don't have a desktop installed, I've just got command line. Not sure, but can't I add something to init.d?

Comment: Didn't know that.. well no, you should use the `crontab` then, as Rich posted above.

Answer (score 1):

All Linux distros use [Vixie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Vixie) cron. It allows starting things on reboot.

If you can stomach [crontab](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/crontab.5.php) config, you can run `crontab -e` and add a simple line like:

```
@reboot /path/to/rtorrent/or/some/script
```

It runs as whatever user owns the crontab, which is you.

For the rtorrent config, since you're on an RPM system, you can query the RPM DB:

```
rpm -q --filesbypkg rtorrent
```

Or, more generally, use locate

```
locate rtorrent.conf
```

Comment: i've started up rtorrent and it is a app that is not run in the background. would not this solution start up the computer and run the app like i would? what about a solution involving "screen rtorrent" to make it startup in another screen? might that work?

Comment: If it's a GUI app, it will probably fail when it can't connect to a XServer. If it's command line, you can run in background by adding '&' to the end of the line in your crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Just run in a terminal `gnome-session-properties`.
For me it worked in fedora 15